# Converting points from cs::cartesian to WGS84

Tags: c++, boost, gis, boost-geometry, wgs84

I have coordinates in cs::cartesian and I want to convert them to WGS84, given reference coordinates for the origin of cs::cartesian.

Is that possible with boost.geometry?

Comment: found this about the state of the projections and their documentation: http://boost-geometry.203548.n3.nabble.com/Geometry-extensions-documentation-coordinate-system-definition-and-conversion-td4025247.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only have only limited knowledge of Boost.Geometry, but it seems it does not offer a straightforward solution to
your problem.

However, converting from cartesian to latitude, longtitude and height (i.e.
ellipsoidal coordinates) is a pretty simple algorithm. You can
find the implementation in [navipedia](http://www.navipedia.net/index.php/Ellipsoidal_and_Cartesian_Coordinates_Conversion).

If you can read FORTRAN, a more efficient implementation can be found in the
[iers software secion](ftp://tai.bipm.org/iers/convupdt/chapter4/GCONV2.F) (with an example which you can use to validate your
results).

Note that if you use the algorithm from navipedia, you will need the parameters
of the ellipsoid WGS84 uses, i.e. a and e which you can find [here](http://www.arsitech.com/mapping/geodetic_datum/).

Comment: Strange how you insist on the formatting handicaps of comments. I think this might be useful but I don't see why you would offer it in such dense layout (and then add chatter too). (**update** edited a bit)